# How is this linear model producing non-linear output?

Tags: linear-model, tensorflow

I trained a 1 unit 1 layer (which I assume is limited to being a linear model) on temperature data, which follows a sinusoidal pattern over time. I expected this limited model to just produce a line around the mean, but if I predict values over time I get this stepped pattern [image: stepped pattern:]

The model creation:

```
  body = tf.keras.Sequential([
    layers.Dense(1)
  ])
```

And the input preprocessing:
[image: input preprocessing]

How is it able to produce this non-linear output? Or an I grossly misunderstanding what Dense(1) creates, or what a linear model can predict?

If I add hidden layers and more units it follows a smooth curve without the steps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The seasonality of the output is very clear. That happens because your input is not only "day" as a number, but rather that as a category (so 31 levels), plus a concatenation of more three features. In particular, you can see the output changes level by month.

Comment: Ahh, I didn't notice the steps perfectly line up to the months. So because I did that work on the inputs, it's allowing a simple linear model to look non linear (to me at least), whereas a simpler input would just produce a line?

Comment: Now I'm imagining how a function could provide this output, with those categories and coefficients. I think. Thank you!